# Blogging using Twitter's Bootstrap?

Tags: blogs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm interested in using bootstrap for a blog, and I've seen a few other sites doing similar things like:

http://www.hostliketoast.com/host-like-toast-home-updates-blog/
http://www.thehubcycleshop.co.uk/blog

My question is, are there any bootstrap plugins or open sourced examples of how to do this? Or will I need to come up with something on my own if I want blog functionality. I'm ideally trying to find something easy to add/update/organize blogs with for bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, Bootstrap isn't a software, it's a design framework that can be integrated into any blogging software that allows you to modify the underlying code.

Wordpress, for example, [provides instructions on their site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/) on how to use Bootstrap with their themes.

Answer (score 1):

We make the WordPress Bootstrap CSS plugin that your referred to earlier, on Host Like Toast.

This plugin is free and open-source, and we have tutorials on the website for how you can use WordPress shortcodes to implement some of the bootstrap features.

You could also, in your themes, use the do_shortcode() function to implement the existing shortcodes easily.

Today we released version 2.0.0-beta so you can immediately start taking full advantage of Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.

Further information is here: http://bit.ly/zU9xrb